# Can I use in a sentence "It could" + if + "it will be"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

The sentence I'm referring to is:

> It could benefit both banks and households if this measure will be applied wisely.

Is it correct?
I can't match it with any of the 4 conditionals form.

Comment: It is easier to answer if you give a full sentences. I can't really tell what sentence you are asking about. Do you mean the following? "It could if it will be."

Comment: The full sentence is present at the beginning of the post (not in the title). I've just edited it to make it more evident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace *will be* with *is* in your sentence. With *is*, you still get the sense of being in the future since it is part of the conditional.

It usually sounds incorrect to have *will* in the condition part of the conditional. There is actually a whole section on Wikipedia, [Use of will and would in condition clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Use_of_will_and_would_in_condition_clauses), directly addressing this. The main exception I can think of are all when used with *you* in the phrase *If you will*, to make a polite request. I don't think that works with other pronouns though.

It is fine to use *will* in the consequence of the conditional, like "If X, it will Y", but that doesn't work in your sentence (it would replace *could*, meaning the measure definitely will have those benefits, not just possibly).

---

A separate concern in this sentence in that the pronoun *it* is introduced first, before what it refers to, *this measure*. I would rephrase to either:

> If this measure is applied wisely, it could benefit both banks and households.

or

> This measure could benefit both banks and households if it is applied wisely.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for the answer. Would you say that using "if" + "will" is uncorrect or just less idiomatic?

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini - Good question. I've edited the answer to address it.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I think about that, it doesn't make sense to use "will", that expresses a certainty, in the condition part of a conditional form. Thanks again!

Comment: @FrancescoAmbrosini - Looks like the Wikipedia article on the conditional has a section on exactly this concern: [Use of will and would in condition clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Use_of_will_and_would_in_condition_clauses)

Comment: I interpreted the initial "it" as a dummy pronoun.